# Are environment variables necessary in PHP to send mail?

Tags: php, email, environment-variables

I have created PHP mail scripts in the past using the built in PHP mail function like this:

```
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

But it's always been on a remote server.

I need to build a contact form on my local WAMP server. I've been given an assignment to create a contact form and to include the environment variables (smpt username and password) in a separate include file.

I'm not exactly sure what this means.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can get access to environmental vars using `getvar('<name>');` this will return the value. Environment vars are values that are set in the unix environment, they are usually set in the .bash files or something other config file, alt they can be applied set by running $`export VAR=1234` from the CLI

Comment: To be honest this question reads like: "Please do my homework for me". You do not even seem to understand 'the assignment'.

Comment: *"...to include the environment variables ... in a separate include file."* - `include ('file.php');` and [`Server and execution environment information`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) should get you started.

Comment: those aren't "environment variables". Those are just php variables (`$username = 'foo'`), or PHP constants (`define('username', 'foo')`. Environment variables exist OUTSIDE of php, and you'd be using getenv() for that.

Comment: Sorry if it seems like I'm asking for someone to do my homework. I just don't understand why they would ask for a username and password to send an email with PHP. It seems that the PHP server would handle sending the email as long as it's set up to send email.

Comment: Why don't you ask them the "why"? @DougSteinberg If they were to shed a bit more light on the subject, you'll be the wiser ;-)